# Datagridview format datetime to translate

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, datagridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOyYR.jpg)

The date field looks like an integer when I upload an excelden file to a Windows.

When I upload an excelled file to a Windows Form without using the database, the date field looks like an integer.

How can I translate my date field to the exact date format in the DataGridView? Defaultcellstyle.format = "dd / MM / yyyy" I want to change the textual sense.

Answer (score 0):

change the format string as below

```
Defaultcellstyle.format = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOyvb.jpg)I tried the code you specified in the screenshot, but I turned to the format I sent.

Code :  dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";